# Subpage disappears from Sitetree after saving it in Silverstripe 3.5.3

Tags: backend, silverstripe

I am pretty new to SilverStripe and would appreciate some advice on this topic. I was not able to find some information about this. 
Every time I edit a Subpage and then save it, it disappears from the SiteTree until I refresh the page, then I can see It again. 
I have no clue why this is happening. Can anyone point me in the right direction please.

**Before saving childpage**

[image: Before saving subpage]

**After saving childpage**

[image: After saving subpage]

Comment: I've seen it before as well, sometimes the page turns up as "child" or "subnode", sometimes it doesn't turn up at all immediately. What modules are you using? It may be caused by a module, I'm not sure.

Comment: Modules I am using: display_logic, fluent, sortablefile, sortablegridfield, linkable, griedfieldextension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the identical problem few days ago.
Now it is fixed.

Problem appeared after I updated "silverstripe/framework" with composer but few other modules left with old versions.

So, update these modules to equal versions
"silverstripe/framework"
"silverstripe/cms"
"silverstripe/reports"
"silverstripe/siteconfig"

I've updated all of them to 3.5.3 and problem disappeared.
It seems like all of them must be the same version cause they are deeply related to each other.

I hope it will help you too.

Comment: What version of cms did you have that caused this issue? I would like to try this out. What an interesting issue.

Comment: At the moment of bug framework was 3.5.3. CMS and other listed modules was 3.5.1.  
Before bug all versions was 3.5.1

Comment: @3dgoo the framework version is 3.5.3 and all other listed modules are also 3.5.3. If you find out what causes this bug please let me know I will do the Same.